# The code in updateHanlder (HealthKit) did not work when the watch enter the background

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2

When the watch' screen is on, I can get the feedback(heart rate data) from the `updateHanlder` block, and do some UI settings(haptic vibration or label setting). However, when I put my wrist down and the screen becomes off, I can not get information NSLoged from the `updateHanlder` block. I am sure the heart rate sensor is still running and the health app in the iOS client shows that the heart rate data is achieved.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830686/hkworkoutsession-not-getting-heartrate-when-screen-is-locked-watchos2

Maybe this is expected behaviour then? When I read the documentation I interpreted it that we could get streaming heart rate data during a HKWorkoutSession

Comment: Release notes from beta 3: 
Fixed in beta 3:
During an active workout session, new heart rate samples are not generated when the screen is off.